# Cannot install julia packages

Tags: julia

I'm having issues installing packages in julia I've downloaded the most current julia release and I've run:

```
Pkg.init()
```

and then I try adding a package and it throws an error. I've deleted the /.julia directory to do a fresh install but nothing seems to be working. Any idea on what is going on?

```
julia> Pkg.add("Distributions")

INFO: Cloning cache of ArrayViews from git://github.com/JuliaLang/ArrayViews.jl.git
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com//JuliaLang/ArrayViews.jl.git/': The requested URL returned error: 400
ERROR: unlink: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
 in wait at task.jl:51
 in sync_end at /Applications/Julia-0.3.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
 in add at pkg/entry.jl:319
 in add at pkg/entry.jl:71
 in anonymous at pkg/dir.jl:28
 in cd at /Applications/Julia-0.3.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
 in __cd#228__ at /Applications/Julia-0.3.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
 in add at pkg.jl:20
```

Version info:

```
julia> versioninfo()

Julia Version 0.3.6
Commit 0c24dca* (2015-02-17 22:12 UTC)
Platform Info:
  System: Darwin (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4650U CPU @ 1.70GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Haswell)
  LAPACK: libopenblas
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.3
```

git command:

```
> git config --get-regexp '^url.*'

url.https://github.com/.insteadof git://github.com
url.https://.insteadof git://
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of `versioninfo()`?

Comment: And the output of `git config --get-regexp '^url.*'` at your shell prompt?

Comment: added both of those pieces of information

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is in your git configuration.  You have two URL rewriting rules in place.  The github-specific one is redundant and is missing the trailing backslash in its match rule.  You can simply delete it:

```
git config --global --unset url.https://github.com/.insteadof
```

Answer (score 3):

Might be a firewall issue, try running

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

as [described in the manual](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/packages/#adding-and-removing-packages).

Comment: Just realized the URL says `https://github.com//JuliaLang/ArrayViews.jl.git/` with an extra `/`, wondering if thats a factor.

Comment: The trailing `/` seems fine - the issue is the double `//` in `github.com//JuliaLang`.  Not sure how that got there or how to remove it, though.  Maybe it's from a different attempt at git url modification?

Comment: I've probably mucked things up a bit more by trying to fix it